# Find an example for a field extension of $F/K$ and suppose that $[F: K] =3$. But F $\ne K(\sqrt[3]{a}) \forall a \in K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Find an example for a field extension of $F/K$ and suppose that $[F:K]$=3. But F $\ne K(\sqrt[3]{a}) \forall a \in K$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean "for some $a \in K$".

Comment: In fact I try to find a counterexample.

Comment: ? I think you don't understand what I wanted to say. Your question, as stated, is kind of boring: Of course we cannot have $F=K(\sqrt[3]{a})$ for all $a \in K$, since this fails for $a=0$ for example.

Comment: I am voting to close because you have not clarified what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extension of the form $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]a)$ where $ a\in \mathbb Q$  is not the cube of a rational number cannot be normal (=Galois) because it does not contain the two other roots of the irreducible polynomial $X^3-a$, since these roots are not real.
So, contrapositively, any **normal** extension of $\mathbb Q$ of degree $3$ is guaranteed to be not of the form $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]a)$.

But do such normal extensions exist?
Yes, they do but they are not so easy to find. Here are two examples:

The first example is the splitting field of the polynomial $X^3+X^2-2X-1$.
If $\alpha$ is one of its roots then the other two are $\alpha^2-2$ and $\alpha^3-3\alpha$, so that indeed the extension $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]a)$ is normal and thus:
 **The degree $3$ extension $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$  is not  of the form $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]a)$  for any $a\in\mathbb Q $**

The second example is obtained by considering the cyclotomic extension of level $9$ of $\mathbb Q$, namely  $K= \mathbb Q(\omega)$ where $\omega =\exp(\frac {2i\pi}{9})$.
The extension $K/\mathbb Q$ is   Galois  of degree $6$, and has cyclic Galois group.
It thus has  a unique subextension $E$ of degree $3$, automatically normal.
That extension is $\mathbb Q(\omega +\omega^{-1})$ and since $\omega +\omega^{-1}=2\cos (\frac {2\pi}{9})$ we conclude:
 **The degree $3$ extension $\mathbb Q( \cos (\frac {2\pi}{9}) ) $ is not of the form $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]a)$ for any $a\in\mathbb Q $**

Answer (score 9):

$\mathbb{F}_{27}$ is an extension of degree $3$ of $\mathbb{F}_3$. Since $a^3=a$ for $a \in \mathbb{F}_3$, we have $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt[3]{a})=\mathbb{F}_3$ for $a \in \mathbb{F}_3$.

Comment: But I want a counterexample

Comment: @chuyenvien94 How is this not a counterexample?

Comment: I try to find a field extension $F/K$ with $[F:K]=3$ but $F\neq F\left(\sqrt[3]{a}\right)\forall a\in K
 $

Comment: @chuyenvien94 As Martin said in the comment to the question, you mean "for some $a\in K$," *not* "for all $a\in K$." In the "for all" case, it is quite easy to find a counterexample: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{3})/\Bbb Q$ is a field extension of degree $3$, but $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{3})\neq\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, so in particular, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{3})\neq\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{a})$ *for all* $a\in\Bbb Q$. However, the *for some* counterexample is given by Martin's answer: $F = \Bbb F_{27}$, $K = \Bbb F_3$.

Comment: And isn't that **exactly** what Martin is showing us, @chuyenvien94 ??

Comment: MartinBrandenburg: of course, for whatever reason I had $2$ and $3$ in my head. First "nontrivial" counterexamples, I suppose.
@chuyenvien94: If we say $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{3}) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{a})$ *for all* $a\in\Bbb Q$, that means that whatever $a\in\Bbb Q$ we choose ($a$ could be 2, 0, even 923/375...), we would have to have that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{3}) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{a})$. That is, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{3})$ would need to equal $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, and it would need to equal $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{0}) = \Bbb Q$, and it would need to equal $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{923/375})$, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

As stated the answer is NO for trivial reasons. Not only taking cubic roots of elements which are already cubes in $K$ (e.g. $0$, $1$, $8$, $27$ $...\in\Bbb Q$) gives no extension but also taking cubic roots of different non cubes yields different extensions, e.g. $3^{1/3}\notin\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$.

A more interesting question would be: Suppose that $F\supset K$ is a cubic extension of fields of characteristic $0$ (positive characteristic is ruled out like in Martin Brandenburg answer), is it then true that $F$ can be obtained by extending $K$ with the cubic root of *some* $a\in K$?

The question is justified by the fact that the answer of the corresponding question for quadratic field is affirmative.

Yet, the answer is stil **no**. Suppose $F\supset\Bbb Q$ is a cubic Galois extension. We know that $F=\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the root of some irreducible polynomial $P(X)\in\Bbb Q[X]$ of degree 3. This polynomial cannot be of the form $X^3-q$ since these polynomials have 1 real root and two complex conjugate roots whereas a Galois extension of degree 3 of $\Bbb Q$ admits only real embeddings.

Comment: "(positive characteristic is ruled out like in Martin Brandenburg answer)" I'm not sure what that means.  Fixing the annoying quantifier error from "all" to "some" as everyone but the OP has done, then in all characteristics there are *some* cubic extensions of the form $F(\sqrt[3]{a})/F$: for any field $k$, take $F = k(t)$ and take $a = t$.  However (as you say) when $\overline{F} \setminus F$ contains 3rd roots of unity these extensions cannot be normal; also in characteristic $3$ they cannot be separable, so under either of these hypotheses a Galois cubic extension gives a counterexample.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: yes, the quoted sentence is vague at best. Let's say that I just wanted to give an answer as elementary as possible in a situation (extensions of the rational field) which the questioner is likely to be more familiar with.

Comment: Under the circumstances it does seem wise to leave a simple answer, yes.  (I would upvote your answer but I seem to be out of votes for today.)